# How to use nginx as a proxy for a private GCS bucket?

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, url-rewriting, google-cloud-storage, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a GCS bucket which is private, and holds all of static media/image files that is used in my website.

Without making the bucket public, I need to have a mechanism for the users to access these resources.

GCS offers "Signed URLs with expiration time" to make these resources available which will be valid only for a specified time. Signed URL generation itself requires google libraries.

I use nginx as a proxy to the website. Does nginx support "plugging in custom logic to generate signed URLs for a resource request, and redirect the request to https://storage.googleapis.com" ?

I have read articles about URL Rewriting in nginx, but none of them solves this scenario which requires "unique URLs" for every request.

Comment: Please, could you post what did you do at the end? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same need and I used a gcsproxy to do it: https://github.com/daichirata/gcsproxy

You may need to make some tries before having exactly what you want but it does the work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) for that.

> Cloud Storage FUSE uses FUSE and Cloud Storage APIs to transparently expose buckets as locally mounted folders on your file system. Cloud Storage FUSE can be run from anywhere with connectivity to Cloud Storage, including Google Kubernetes Engine, Compute Engine VMs, or on-premises systems.

Then, point your Nginx endpoints to read the static files mounted from the private bucket:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /mount-point;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
}
```